# Atom manipulating editor DOM

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I'm trying to write a plugin for atom, but the approach I've taken must wrong. I'm trying to add new classes to certain elements of the editor, which works initially, but after scrolling, the DOM is re-written and the classes are removed. What's the correct approach to persist changes to editor's DOM?

```
function manipulateEditor({shadowRoot}) {
  const elements = shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.brace');

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let {classList} = elements[i];
    classList.add('my-class');
  }
}

atom.workspace.observeTextEditors(editor => {
  const view = atom.views.getView(editor);
  const manipulate = manipulateEditor.bind(null, view);
  editor.onDidStopChanging(manipulate);
  manipulate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm supposed to be using the Decoration API.

https://discuss.atom.io/t/keep-mutated-dom-on-scroll/23553/2